# Not understanding help files, case automatic deleted q/post

Tags: support, deleted-questions, rules, automatic-deletion

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631075/regina-5-5-3-scoping-at-work-the-classic-accumulator-test-perl-example). The title was:

> ReGina - 5.5.3 Scoping at work: the classic accumulator test - Perl example [closed]

I can see that it is automated closed. There was the message:

> deleted by Community Jun 29 at 3:00 (RemoveAbandonedClosed)
>   This question was automatically deleted. Please see the help center for more information.

I did follow the link and read. I do not understand why my question was deleted. Can someone please explain to me?

What I have seen is that my q had -6. But I do not understand, what should be wrong with a question about a not working example in a Groovy book.

I would like to learn the reason why my question was deleted as I see the possibility to step in this trap again and I want to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I only doubt I can't see the necessary buttons. I do have here only the "add a comment" link. Where should I click to "flag" it and how do I contact a moderator? Thanks in advance

Comment: "RemoveAbandonedClosed" -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Answer (score 8):

> But I do not understand, what should be wrong with a question about a not working example in a Groovy book.

Me neither. If that was the question, then it might be *boring*, but it should be on-topic.

However, you are misrepresenting [the question that you actually asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631075/regina-5-5-3-scoping-at-work-the-classic-accumulator-test-perl-example). The body consisted solely of the following text:

> in ReGina (Groovy in Action, Second Edition) in chapter 5.5.3 Scoping at work: the classic accumulator test - there is a Perl example.
> This example seems to not work. Has anybody ever made this Perl-snippet to run?
> Would be thankful for hints.
> Thanks in advance, Thomas

Even putting aside the grammar mistakes, the lack of formatting, and the unnecessary signature, there is a larger problem: **you forgot to include the code from the example that didn't work!**

In fact, this is precisely why your question got closed by community members:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That is, as usual, a very apt description of the problems with your question, so it was rightfully closed.

Then, after the question was closed, you essentially abandoned it. You did not bother to go back and update the question (edit it) to include the missing information. So the system automatically deleted it to clean up clutter. This is a process that we affectionately call the "Roomba", after [the autonomous vacuum cleaner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba).

In particular, the rule that caused your question to be deleted was "RemoveAbandonedClosed", which [that Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) describes as follows:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as RemoveAbandonedClosed.